# Add cloud speech recognition to Pepper QiSDK

Tags: android, pepper

I am currently working with a Pepper robot (academic version and the QiSDK and NaoQi 2.9). Since I am using the academic version I can't use the cloud based automatic speech recognition service from Softbank which is not included and therefore e.g. I can't use wildcards or other chatbot engines besides QiChat. 
Does anybody of you know how I can implement my own speech recognition service for Pepper? I can't find where I can get access to the audiostream of Pepper's microphones.

I've read the documentation from Softbank: 
https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk
and 
https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/reference/basechatbot.html

And I've tried to create a SpeechRecognizer based on Android, which works, but uses the Tablets microphone and not Peppers.

Comment: How is the performance with the tablet mics? Maybe you dont even want/need to use Peppers microphones. In my experience the signal from the head mics has fan noises and sounds from joint movements and therefore is not ideal for asr. (I tested this with NaoQi 2.5 and cant help with Android)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The performance is actually not so bad, but I think the microphones of Pepper are a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Speech Recognition is a service that you will need to by on top if it was not included with your original Pepper offer!

Regards,
Jonas

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your answer. I was told that it is not possible at the moment to buy this service, that's why I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Oh sorry, then tablet mic is your only option I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I was also curious and contacted the softbank support.

Summary:

With version 2.9. you have no access to the head microphones and can only access the tablet mic.